# Using Image Upload LWC to build Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, button

I want to build a LWC to run in a flow, that will upload an image in Flow Builder and then display the image on the flow to use as a navigation button.

Any idea on how I can build this so the image upload is done in the builder but doesn't display in the flow?

Comment: I guess this can be achieved by standard file upload. Are you having any specific issue on which we can help?

Comment: I actually wanted upload the file in the custom property editor, but I found a workaround. Thanks.